# Midi Files Sound different on Android Device

Tags: android, midi

I'm ripping my hair out at the lack of documentation and help available for the jetcreator and jetplayer in Android.  What I have are a set of Midi files that sound just fine when played using the EASSynth Plugin inside a DAW (which emulates how android should sound), it goes into jetcreator just fine, sounds great.

But when it comes time to actually play the file on the device, several tracks are consistently defaulting to the piano instrument.  I thought it was a DLS issue but changing the DLS didn't fix the problem...this really makes no sense to me being as EASSynth is supposed to emulate Android's default DLS sounds so something is definitely going wrong.

Here are a few liens from my code, I'm semi convinced the problem is not with the jet file but with the code itself:

```
jet = JetPlayer.getJetPlayer();
jet.loadJetFile(wrapper.getResources().openRawResourceFd(fileID));
jet.queueJetSegment(song.ID(), -1, -1, 0, 0, (byte)0);
```

Could it have to do with the user just being (byte)0? it only has to do with events so I didn't think it made much of a difference.

Comment: Finally figured out the cause. If a segement in jetcreator does not start at 1:1:0 of a midi file, it messes up the instrumentation as described above.  But this means I can't put all my music into a single MIDI....which sucks

Comment: Now it appears that some files follow the above rules but others don;t and I can;t find a single damn thing different between them x_x  This is so frustrating lol

Comment: currently investigating if the source of the problem is finale, the program used by my composer to expert the midis.  It's not really meant for midi generation and I bet it's encoding the files a weird way.